# "Start to the week" vs "Start of the week"

Tags: prepositions, style

I feel that normally one would say "start of the week" in a sentence, but I noticed that sometimes "start **to** the week" is used, most notably in "Have a great start to the week!".

Is this an outlier or are there more examples with "to" instead of "of"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same with, for example, the *start **of** the day*, which normally refers to ***the early hours of the day***. Whereas eating a hearty breakfast gives you a good *start **to** the day*.

The ***of*** versions are for referring to a particular (static) ***time*** (day or hour). The ***to*** versions are for referring to a (dynamic) ***process***.

The same distinction arises with references *the start **of / to** the month / year / decade / ...* Or indeed *a perfect end **to** a perfect day*, which you might say at *the end **of** the day*.

Comment: Could you give examples to illustrate the static/dynamic distinction? I don't quite follow.

Comment: When we refer to the *start / middle / end **of** the day / week / month / year*, we're primarily talking about a ***specific time / date*** (the "day / week / month" is only mentioned because it narrows down the specific time we want to reference. But in the ***to*** versions we're primarily talking about the "day / week / month" itself - with its good or bad start or end. It might help if you note that you'll *never* encounter a reference to *a good / bad **middle to** the day*, but *I have a nap in the **middle of** the day* is perfectly natural.

Comment: Ah, I think you're saying that to refer to a moment in time, rather than a period of time, it has to be with "of": e.g. "the start to the meeting went well" sounds better than "the start to the meeting was delayed". But "the start of the meeting went well" also sounds OK to my ears.

Comment: In *The start to/of the week went well* I'd say either preposition works (but the phrasing is a bit klunky anyway - we'd say *The week started well*). And although I prefer ***of*** in *The start to/of his presentation was delayed*, I wouldn't like to argue against ***to*** (except when arguing against *both*, in favour of removing ***The start of/to*** completely). I think maybe if "the start/end of/to [something with duration]" is the syntactic *subject* (often, "awkward phrasing") there's more flexibility than when it's the *object*.

Comment: There's also an issue regarding ***start / middle / end*** being used as *nouns* (to reference some "subsection" of the day / week / meeting), where I've pointed out that it's often more natural to convert them to *verbs* *(The day started well, The meeting ended badly)*. Bear in mind that we're getting a long way from "fixed grammatical rules" here. Also, I doubt I've ever heard anyone say anything like *Have a good start to the week* (Why just the start? Why not *Have a good week*?). But it's almost always *It's a sad end **to** the week / We met at the start **of** the month*.